# Can I use/import my ARCore project (in Unity) to my Flutter project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, flutter, arcore

I wonder if anyone did this before or know how to. I've been surving the net for a while and got a lot of confusions about this.

Can someone make it straight for me?

Regards,
SlimmZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this dependancy for your project:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget